# Repeater - textbox content to database C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to insert content to my local database from a textbox inside a repeater element, in a post - comment way. So far I've tried looping on all the generated rows to find the specific textbox but I have had no luck, either the insert goes empty, or I get 1 insert per preexisting row, or I get the same value inserted over and over again through different posts.

I finally tried to pass the post id to the itemfinder and it's kind of working, but the "comm_contenido" inserts from the textbox are still going empty to the database.

My question is what it the correct and more direct way to handle these kind of inserts from within a Repeater?.

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    string postid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string emailcc = Session["EMAIL"].ToString();
    string user_id = Session["ID"].ToString();
    string usrnom = Session["NOMBRE"].ToString();
    string usrfoto = Session["FOTO_URL"].ToString();
    //string COMM_CONTENIDO = lblcomm.Text.ToString();

    var COMM_fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    TextBox txt2;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionBD"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                int m = Int32.Parse(postid);
                txt2 = (TextBox)Repeater_UsrPosts.Items[m].FindControl("txtcomentar");
                string txt1 = txt2.Text;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO MIEMBROS_Comments (COMM_USER_ID, COMM_CONTENIDO, COMM_FECHA, COMM_USER_NOMBRE, COMM_USER_FOTO, COMM_POST_ID) VALUES ('"
                + user_id + "','" + txt1 + "','" + COMM_fecha + "','" + usrnom + "','" + usrfoto + "','" + postid + "');");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        //txtpublica.Text = "";
        traerposts();

}
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_UsrPosts" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>

        <!-- Post -->
        <div class="post clearfix">
            <div class="user-block">



                <img alt="" src="<%#Eval("post_user_foto")%>" class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" />

                <span class="username">
                    <a href="#"><%#Eval("post_user_nombre") %></a>
                    <a href="#" class="pull-right btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </span>
                <span class="description"><%#Eval("post_fecha") %></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.user-block -->

            <p>

                <%#Eval("post_contenido") %>
            </p>

            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-share margin-r-5"></i>Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i>Like</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="bttnabrircomentarios" runat="server" class="link-black text-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments-o margin-r-5"></i>Comments</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomentar" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Escribe un comentario" EnableViewState="False"></asp:TextBox>

            <%# Eval("post_id") %> -

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
                OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="myCommand"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("post_ID") %>' />
            <br />
        </div>
        <!-- /.post -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: show the loading into the repeater code. Is it being loaded in every post? BTW, once you get it working you should move one step further and avoid the SQL Injection present in your code.

Comment: The textbox is loading on every post, yes. And thanks, I'll do it as soon as I get this working.

Comment: You should not load it on every post. If the event `Button1_Command` fires after your data loading event, I assume `Page_Load`, then the data inserted by the user will be lost.  Load the data only once, check the `Page.IsPostback` property. Edit: just read the answer refering the IsPostBack... Check Omar's answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This were the changes that worked for me to locate the specific textbox and prevent posting unwanted data.

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    string postid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string emailcc = Session["EMAIL"].ToString();
    string user_id = Session["ID"].ToString();
    string usrnom = Session["NOMBRE"].ToString();
    string usrfoto = Session["FOTO_URL"].ToString();

    var COMM_fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

> ```
>     Control s = (Control)sender;
>     TextBox tb = (TextBox)s.NamingContainer.FindControl("txtcomentar");
>     tb.ReadOnly = true;
> ```

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionBD"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            string txt1 = tb.Text;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO MIEMBROS_Comments (COMM_USER_ID, COMM_CONTENIDO, COMM_FECHA, COMM_USER_NOMBRE, COMM_USER_FOTO, COMM_POST_ID) VALUES ('"
            + user_id + "','" + txt1 + "','" + COMM_fecha + "','" + usrnom + "','" + usrfoto + "','" + postid + "');");
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    traerposts();
}
```

And on the ASP I added the property **EnableVIewState="true"** to the textbox and also to the repeater.

At last, most important, I added **if (!Page.IsPostBack)** to the onload event.

And with all this together the comments on each post are being inserted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the `TextBox` Control by assigning `OnTextChanged` to it, and you can also assign its `AutoPostBack` to `true` if you wanted to reach the data immediately.

but you should use `if(!IsPostBack)` before you bind your data to your repeater, so it doesn't reset your `Controls` before you could reach the data.

`OnTextChanged` needs two parameter, one of them is the `sender` object which is calling it, That's your `TextBox`, something like..

ASP

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterExample" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxExample" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBoxExample_OnTextChanged"/>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

Behind Code

```
protected void TextBoxExample_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;
    //Response.Write(txt.Text);
    //or whatever you want to do with it.
}
```

and if you wanted to use it with `Button_OnClick`, you should use like a global string you can call later, you can do something like this..

ASP

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonExample" OnClick="ButtonExample_OnClick"/>
```

Behind Code

```
private string text = "";

protected void TextBoxTest_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    text = txt.Text;
}

protected void ButtonExample_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Response.Write(text);
}
```

but the last method will take the value of the last `TextBox` whose text has changed, unless you add it together like..

```
text += txt.Text;
```

Hope, I could help..

Comment: Your answer fits on another scenario, It's not working for me since I'm using the button command to bring the post ID.